# How can I autofill to the last row containing a value using a macro, with multiple different formulas in one column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formatting, autofill

I am creating a template where a table of values downloaded from a report can be pasted in to an input tab, and return those values in a formatted table on another tab with some formula in between.

Columns C, D & E contain parts 1, 2 and 3 of an items code, and column F contains the row titles (e.g. available quantity, invoiced orders etc..).

Columns after that (G to Z) mostly contain lookups which would be looking up a concatenation of columns C, D, E and F, which appears in column B. Rows 12 and 24, however, have different formula, and rows 15 & 16 contain no formula. Data for one item takes up 13 rows (between rows 12 and 24).

I have been trying to find a macro that can, as if I were selecting the range B12:Z24, drag/autofill the formula and formatting down to the last row that contains value "X" in column A. The "X" in column A indicated whether there is a value in the corresponding row on the input tab, and can vary between appearing in 500 rows to 8000 rows.

I'm a bit of a beginner and so whatever I write is quite basic, but here is what I've tried:

```
Sub FillDown()    
  Range("B12:Z24" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown    
End Sub
```

This works just the same as any more complex code i've pulled from google.

Here is an example of the [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55ZE2.png)

Here is en example of the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqUkY.png)

Anything that i've tried just copies/autofills the formula and formatting from row 12 downwards, rather than the whole section of the table.. any suggestions?

**

- UPDATE

**
Apologies, I figured this one out a couple of weeks ago but forgot to post on here:
Instead of creating new sections (i'm calling rows 12 to 24 "sections"), I created a table with a set number of sections and got some help with a loop that converted the formulas from row 13 to row 23 (I wanted to keep the formula in rows 12 and 24), and did the same for the sections below. Takes some time on larger ranges but does the job.
**Code:**

```
Sub Pasteloop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim j As Long
Dim jj As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Output")

LastRow = 130 'a number 1 bigger than the last row to paste
i = 13       'start row of the 1st select
ii = 23     'end row of the 1st select
j = 13      'start row of the 2nd select
jj = 23     'end row of the 2nd select
k = 7      'column number of the left hand column of the range
p = 260      'column number of the right hand column of the range

'This is the beginning of the loop
Do While i < LastRow
'set the next range as the previous range values
sht1.Range(Cells(j, k), Cells(jj, p)) = sht1.Range(Cells(i, k), Cells(ii, 
p)).Value
'move along to the next selection by incrementing everything by 12
ii = ii + 12
i = i + 12
jj = jj + 12
j = j + 12
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This has reduced opening times of weekly updated reports from minutes to seconds.

Comment: Screenshots should include Column headers if your code relies on it. Why do you fill down column B in code? You need to find the last row of your data.

Comment: @PatricK Apologies, i'll update the screenshots. I suppose column B doesn't have to be included, but for the sake of minimizing the amount of formula overall, i'll only have that copied down to where there is relevant data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating new sections (i'm calling rows 12 to 24 "sections"), I created a table with a set number of sections and got some help with a loop that converted the formulas to values from row 13 to row 23 (I wanted to keep the formula in rows 12 and 24), and did the same for the sections below. Takes some time on larger ranges but does the job. Code:

```
Sub Pasteloop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim j As Long
Dim jj As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Output")

LastRow = 130 'a number 1 bigger than the last row to paste
i = 13       'start row of the 1st select
ii = 23     'end row of the 1st select
j = 13      'start row of the 2nd select
jj = 23     'end row of the 2nd select
k = 7      'column number of the left hand column of the range
p = 260      'column number of the right hand column of the range

'This is the beginning of the loop
Do While i < LastRow
'set the next range as the previous range values
sht1.Range(Cells(j, k), Cells(jj, p)) = sht1.Range(Cells(i, k), Cells(ii, 
p)).Value
'move along to the next selection by incrementing everything by 12
ii = ii + 12
i = i + 12
jj = jj + 12
j = j + 12 
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This has reduced opening times of weekly updated reports from minutes to seconds, and is more efficient than a copy/paste code that would do the same job, and enables you to use your clipboard whilst the code is running which you wouldnt be able to do with a copy/paste code.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to make the data visually invisible on all except the "Available Qty" row, use conditional formatting

your example starts at row 12

cell C12   .... conditional format .... use formula to determine cell format .... formula .... =C11 ....  color white on white (set to red for testing)

then copy format to the three columns as far down as you like

Comment: Please see updated "Desired result" screenshot, may make it a bit clearer what I am looking to do